# cx_freeze windows 32 program won't work

Tags: python, user-interface, cx-freeze

I am having a problem when trying to create an executable with cx_freeze. I have already created an exe from my code but it would not work on 32 bit PC's. To solve that problem, I uninstalled the 64 bit of Python, cx_freeze, and PyQt4(what I am using for the GUI). I then installed all the 32 bit equivalents of those programs. This is when things start to go wrong...

I can run the program fine through the .py file, but when I try to build the program and run it, I get this error window:

[image]

How would I be able to solve this?

Comment: If at all possible, please try to copy the _text_ of the error and paste it in your question, rather than posting a screenshot somewhere else (especially somewhere transient). If you don't know how to copy the traceback out of the error window, just run the setup script in a cmd.exe "DOS prompt" window and copy it from there.

Comment: Meanwhile, you "installed the 64 bit equivalents of those programs", but you're trying to run them in 32-bit Python? That's almost certainly not going to work. Why would you even expect it to?

Comment: @abarnert i meant to say that i installed the 32 bit equivalents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that there's something wrong with the latest release of cx_Freeze on Windows 32 bit. An issue has been filed for it here, but there's no good answer yet: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/59/sre_constantserror-nothing-to-repeat .

Some people have reported that using the previous release ([from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/4.3.1/cx_Freeze-4.3.1.win32-py3.3.msi/download)) worked for them.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It worked after i installed that version of cx_Freeze! I would up vote you if I had more experience :(